# DOMDocument : how to parse a bbcode like tag?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a problem with a query I use with DOMDocument.
I will use a "bbcode like" tag into a string and find the attribute data_id.

I use thp code below but I always get these warning :
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

The "bbcode like" code i want tu use :

```
[sondage data_id=1]
```

The PHP CODE

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($row->text);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//[sondage');

foreach($result as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('data_id');
}
```

Thank your for your help

Comment: Its not valid HTML so there's nothing to parse.

Comment: Sorry, DOMDocument only accepts XML-tags.

Comment: @Youri have you an another solution ? to get all bbcode tags and get the data_id attribute ?

Answer (score -1):

As other people have already pointed out, bbcode isn't value XML markup, so isn't going to be parsed.

Assuming that all your square brackets are parts of BBCode (A big assumption, granted), you could 'replace' them with angle brackets to make them look like tags:

```
$text = str_replace(array("[","]"),array("<",">"),$row->text;
//$text now contains 'XML-ised' content
```

However, if you have any square brackets that are not BBCode, it's probable that it will break...

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to get all your BBCode elements, and then parse them further from there:

```
$text = $row->text;
preg_match_all('#\[[a-z]+.*?\](.*?)\[/[a-z]+\]#is',$text,$matches);
//$matches will contain all your BBCode, which you can then parse further as required.
```